# Get String value in HTML (JSP) button

Tags: java, html, jsp

I Have this HTML tag

```
<button type="submit" name=<%=s %> value=<%=s %>><%=s%></button>
```

The <%=s %> is a String stored in server with white spaces, like "file one".

My problem is in getting the button name. I'm using the following piece of code:

```
String btnName = request.GetParameter(s);
```

It is working, unless if the string presents spaces like "file one". In this case, the part   " one" is ignored.

How can I get the whole String?

Thx.

Comment: Attributes should be in quotes, and [you should be using EL instead of scriptlets.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but did you try surrounding it within double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Put it like the following.

```
<button type="submit" name='<%=s %>' value='<%=s %>'><%=s%></button>
```

Note the new single quotes.

Comment: I'll heavily suggest you to read/study [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The problem would still remain even if they use EL or JSTL, as long as they don't have quotes.

Comment: The problem is that `name` attribute should not contain any spaces =\. Note that OP has this `s` String with a value like *file one*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Not necessarily. try this
<html>
<body>
<form>
<button type="submit" name='my name' value='ha ha ha'>test ok</button>
</form><script language='javascript'>alert(document.forms[0]['my name'].value);</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: test it on your servlet :)

Comment: Thank you guys, I really apreciate your help. And I will try your suggestions